# Array of character defined inside a quotation marks?

Tags: java, string

I got this example code from here:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_copyvalueof.htm

```
public class Test{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      char[] Str1 = "This is really not immutable!!";
      String Str2;

      Str2 = copyValueOf( Str1 );
      System.out.println("Returned String " + Str2);

      Str2 = copyValueOf( Str1, 5, 10 );
      System.out.println("Returned String " + Str2);

   }
}
```

This code is not working for me.

1. array of character is defined as a String.
2. copyValueOf is not recognisable!

Now I change it to this:

```
    char[] Str1 = {'t','o','o','k'};
      String Str2;

      Str2 = copyValueOf( Str1 );
      System.out.println("Returned String " + Str2);

      Str2 = copyValueOf( Str1, 5, 10 );
      System.out.println("Returned String " + Str2);
```

Still copyValueOf is not working?
I have checked this method and it exist on documentation!

Comment: The place you got it from is publishing 100% non-compiling drivel, and should be avoided in future.

Answer (score 4):

1. Unlike C, `char[]` is not a `String`, and vice versa.
2. You need to specify the class:

   ```
   Str2 = String.copyValueOf( Str1 );
   ```

Comment: That's right. Now it works fine. Silly websites put wrong example. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 3):

You might be missing a [static import](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_import) from your code. Add this to the top of your file:

```
import static java.lang.String.copyValueOf;
```

Alternately, you could ([and perhaps should](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=195)) specify the class explicitly. Since [`copyValueOf` is a static member of `String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#copyValueOf%28char%5B%5D%29) that would look like this:

```
String.copyValueOf(Str1);
```

Comment: +1 I was not aware of static import (although I think `String.copyValueOf` is better) thanks!

Comment: @Bernard - Then perhaps the code example you're using is meant for a newer version of Java than you're working with. Static imports were new to Java 5.

Comment: @Bernard - Try running the command `java -showversion` from the command line; if the `java version "X.X.X"` number is less than `1.5`, you won't be able to use static imports. I think. I'm not a pro with this  Java version stuff...

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen : import static java.lang.String.copyValueOf; did not work for me but when I used the class explicitly it works fine.

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen Here is the java version "1.6.0_37"

Answer (score 0):

Here are the problems:

- You cannot assign a char array by a string. They are different in Java. You can see [Post: Converting String to Character array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006165/converting-string-to-character-array-in-java) for an example of that.
- You should use `String.copyValueOf()` as it is a static class method of `String`.