# Reading File into a char[] array or arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, char

I need to read text from the user and create an array which contains characters so that I can run them through a FSM. However, I can't seem to get the buffered reader to agree with a non-string type of input. Any advice? I also don't know if I should be using an array or arraylist

```
 static ArrayList<Character> StringList = new ArrayList<Character>();
static char[] data;
 public static void main(String[] args){

    InputStreamReader ISR = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
    BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(ISR);
    try{
        String sCurrentChar;
        while((sCurrentChar=BR.readLine())!=null){

            for(int i= 0; i<sCurrentChar.length(); i++)
            StringList.add(sCurrentChar.charAt(i));


        }
       for(int i =0; i<StringList.size(); i++){
           System.out.println(StringList.get(i));
       }
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Better to use char[] instead of list here

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006165/converting-string-to-character-array-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the following could work for you, if you want to read raw byte data, maybe using them later as characters. This might be a better approach than reading input line at a time.

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class a {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(System.in);
    int[] bytes = new int[256];

    try {
      int b;
      int l = 0;
      while((b = d.readByte()) > 0) {
        bytes[l++] = b;
        if((l % 256) == 0)
          bytes = Arrays.copyOf(bytes, (l + 256));
      }
    } catch(EOFException e) {
      // end-of-file
    } catch(IOException e) {
      System.err.println("AIEEEE: " + e);
      System.exit(-1);
    }

    for(int i = 0; bytes[i] > 0; i++) System.out.print((char)bytes[i]);
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

The way arrays are treated here is probably a fine example how one should not do it, but then again, this is more about reading bytes/unsigned characters of data than efficiently processing arrays.