# Converting a String phrase into chars

Tags: java, string, char

I am working on a ShiftCipher program, and i'm looking to convert a string sentence (" This is an example") to chars, to i can shift the sentence over 2 letters.
Input: "THIS IS AN EXAMPLE"
output:"VJKU KU CP GZCORNG"

with the spaces intact. But i'm not sure how I can convert it to a char, shift the text and then convert it back into a char.

Comment: I'd advise reading the javadoc for the `String` class. You'll find useful methods there, and remember that a char is an unsigned 16 bit value that can be incremented just like an int.

Comment: you can do it with `charAt` or `indexOf`, check if it's an space, if true, skip it, else make your algorithm

Comment: one google away: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006165/converting-string-to-character-array-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to convert string into char array.
Do this:

```
String str = "Your input"; 
char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
```

Then you will have to loop through every single char and shift it over by 2.

```
for(int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++)
    charArray[i] += 2;
```

And then convert the char array with shifted characters back to string.

```
String output = new Strin(charArray);
```

And there you have it.

I do advice you read up on [String class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) but if you do not and simply copy my answer, then no one will cry for you because you fail the class by not putting effort into homework.

Comment: Thanks, i figured it out before i saw your answer actually. But i appreciate the advice.

Comment: @user3507670 Glad I could be of some help. However please, mark as solved so we can move along and so that this does not show up in the unanswered queue.