# java split each letter and put it in table

Tags: java, class, methods, split

I would like to create a method that can cut the word variable and put each letter in the array `tab[]`.

Here is my effort.

```
public class Mot {

    private String mot;
    private String tab[];
    //getter et setter
    public String getMot() {
        return mot;
    }

    public void setMot(String mot) {
        this.mot = mot;
    }
    //constructeur plein
    public Mot(String mot, String[] tab) {
        this.mot = mot;
        this.tab = tab;
    }

    //constructeur vide
    public Mot(){

    }
    //methodes
    public void affichage(){
        System.out.println(this.tab[1]);
    }
    //placage de chaque lettre dans un tableau
    public void tableau(){
        this.tab = this.mot.split(mot);        
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if your code is terrible or not but I have absolutely no idea what's meant to be what.

Comment: I don't get it, could you provide example inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: post some input and expected output

Comment: Sorry I express myself badly.

I would like to use the value of "mot" in a method that would return me a table with a letter in each box.
mot = "toto";
tab [0] = "t"
tab [1] = "o"
tab [2] = "t"
tab [3] = "o"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413586/string-to-string-array-conversion-in-java

Comment: I think it might help if you translated this into English, particularly that last comment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006165/converting-string-to-character-array-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split your word or `mot` variable, simply use `String#toCharArray`

```
char[] letters = this.mot.toCharArray();
```

This will let you navigate the string per-character using an `int` index.

I'm not entirely certain how you want to assign the word to the `tab[]` table however, seeing as it is a `String` type but it seems you want characters in it. If you want `tab[]` to simply be the characters in the string, then just assign it accordingly with the return value of `toCharArray`

If they absolutely must be strings, then you can just translate it to a String array of characters:

```
char[] raw = this.mot.toCharArray();
this.tab = new String[raw.length];
for(int i = 0; i < raw.length; i++) {
    this.tab[i] = Character.toString(raw[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, you want to retrieve each character and store it in the Array of Strings `tab[]`.

You could try this method.

```
public void separate_each () {
  int length = mot.length();
  tab = new String[length];
  for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
    tab[index] = mot.charAt(index) + "";
}
```

Hope it helps ^^

Answer (score 0):

I would declare tab as an array of chars:

```
private char[] tab;
```

you could then split the word like this:

```
tab = mot.toCharArray();
```

a char can always be converted into a String when needed:

```
String s = Character.toString(ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        String [] test="789455555".split("");
        for(String s:test)
            System.out.println(s);
    }
```