# Trouble writing a method that takes a string and returns an array of chars

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I'm new to Java and stuck on the code below. I don't know how to return the char array; and also if I change the string `"purple"` to something else, Java won't compile the code.

```
public class Assigment4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // I get an error if color is initialized with a longer or shorter string.
        String color = "purple"; 
        char[] a = turnStringtoChar(color);
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    public static char[] turnStringtoChar(String color) {
        char[] letters = {'p', 'u', 'r', 'p', 'l', 'e'};

        for (int i = 0; i < color.length(); i++) {
            // This is the part where I am stuck. I don't know what to return.
            letters[i] = color.charAt(i);
        }

        return letters;
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you want `letters.length` to be (i.e., how many elements do you want in it)?  What is `letters.length` the way you've written it?  (And I don't believe that the program doesn't compile if you change the string.  It probably throws an exception when you run it.  This is _not_ the same as saying it won't compile.  It is important to learn the difference.)

Comment: Couldn't you just use `toCharArray()`? You could do something like `char[] a = color.toCharArray()`

Comment: i could but i have to create my own method to convert the string into an array of chars

Comment: Look at String's .charAt() method if you can't use toCharArray(). Or is that also not allowed?

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006165/converting-string-to-character-array-in-java.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your `turnStringtoChar` method, you need to declare the `letters` character array in such a way that its `length` is **dependent** on the length of the `color` variable.
So if you have an input that is longer than `"purple"`; e.g: `"yellowwwww"`;
your program will not throw any errors.

```
//this is what I am talking about
char[] letters = new char[color.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < color.length(); i++) {
    // this is okay!
    letters[i] = color.charAt(i);
}
```

**Note**: I understand this is an assignment and have to implement your own implementation, but for future use, you can use `toCharArray()` method from `String` class. usage: `color.toCharArray()`

Comment: Call me crazy, but the requirement is to create your own method.  You could simply do this:

    `public char[] turnStringtoChar(String color)
    {
        return color.toCharArray();
    }`

After all, you are already using the String API for other purposes.  Might as well take full advantage of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
char[] chars = new char [str.length()];
for (int i=0;i <str.length ();i++) {
    chars [i] = str.charAt (i);
}
```