# Java - how to break a integer into its digits

Tags: java, integer, int

newbie here. I'm practicing Data Structures and Algorithms for interviews. I'm stuck at this situation, where basically it requires to break down an integer (Eg. 615) to its digits (Eg. 6, 1, 5). I did find a solution online, however I feel there has to be a better and simpler way to do this?

Here is the solution that I found -

```
 int total = sum1 + sum2; //This is the number we want to split
 Integer totalInt = new Integer(total);
 String strSum = totalInt.toString();

 for (int i = 0; i < strSum.length(); i++) {
  String subChar = strSum.substring(i, i + 1);
  int nodeData = Integer.valueOf(subChar);
  newList.append(new Node(nodeData)); //irrelevant in context of question
 }
```

Comment: What about [toCharArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006165/converting-string-to-character-array-in-java)

Comment: @BogdanKuštan yea I kinda thought about that but the problem is that it'll store digits as char(s) and we want them to remain int. Makes sense?

Comment: So You could use `Character.getNumericValue(element.charAt(0));` or are these expensive? I am not very good at Java, but this is clean way, don't know how fast it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one works with any base:

```
int input = yourInput;
final int base = 10; //could be anything
final ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
while(input != 0) {
    result.add(input % (base));
    input = input / base;
}
```

If you need the digits ordered so that the most significant one is the first, you could use a `Stack` instead of a `List` for the result variable.

Answer (score 2):

A way you can make your method multi-purpose is by making it a `Spliterator`. That means it can produce a stream of `Integer` that can be used for any purpose: sum them, add them to a list, whatever.

If you're not familiar with spliterators, here's an example:

```
public class Digitiser implements Spliterators.OfInt {
    private int currentValue;
    private final int base;
    public Digitiser(int value, int base) {
        currentValue = value;
        this.base = base;
    }
    public boolean tryAdvance(IntConsumer action) {
        if (currentValue == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            int digit = value % base;
            value /= base;
            action.accept(digit);
            return true;
        }
    }
    public static IntStream stream(int value, int base) {
        return StreamSupport.intStream(new Digitiser(value, base), false);
}
```

Now you've got a general purpose digitiser that can be used to do all sorts of things:

```
Digitiser.stream(13242, 10).sum();
Digitiser.stream(42234, 2).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends exactly what you're trying to do with the broken-up digits; but for an example, here is a way to add up the digits of a positive integer:

```
int sumOfDigits = 0;
while (n > 0) {
    final int lastDigit = n % 10;    // remainder of n divided by 10
    sumOfDigits += lastDigit;
    n /= 10;                         // divide by 10, to drop the last digit
}
```

Comment: My bad... I'll leave this here for you to see, then delete the comment in 30, 29, 28....

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
int total = 123; //This is the number we want to split
Integer totalInt = new Integer(total);
String strSum = totalInt.toString();
String nums[] = strSum.split("");

// First element will be empty
// Changed loop initial value i to 0 from 1
for( int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++ ) {
    System.out.println(nums[i]);
    // Or if you want int from it, then
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(nums[i]));
}
```

Output :

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use toCharArray():

```
char[] digits = strSum.toCharArray();
```

Then, convert it to int[]:

```
int[] numbers = new int[digits.length]; 

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    numbers[i] = digits[i] - '0';
}
```

Comment: that works, but I want to keep those digits as int and not char. char[] will store them as char(s)...Any solution?

Comment: Why do you want store the digits as integer?

Comment: Because thats what the problem requires. Eg. After getting those digits, I may want to perform mathematical operations on them. I will not be able to do that if those digits are in char format...

Comment: So, after toCharArray, you must convert the result to int[]. Update d the answer.