# What is the best and effective way to read chars from string in java

Tags: java, string, chars

I want to know the effective way of reading a string which does not affect memory nor performance of the program.

***I have the following implementation:***

```
String x = "<BigBus><color>RED</color><number>123</number>........</BigBus>";
    char[] xh = new char[x.length()];
    for(int i=0;x.length();i+) {
       ch[i]=x.charAt(i);
       System.out.println(ch[i]);
    }
```

The sample string larger and have multiple lines.

Comment: Duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006165/converting-string-to-character-array-in-java

Comment: I will keep with your implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution will be to use ***Java 8*** features for this.

Method `chars()` returns chars from given string. But it prints just char number value. For convenience we have to add utility method:

```
public class IterateString {

    private static void printChar(int aChar) {
        System.out.println((char) (aChar));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "<BigBus><color>RED</color><number>123</number>........</BigBus>";

        str.chars()
                .forEach(IterateString::printChar);

        // other options
        System.out.println();
        str.chars()
            .mapToObj(ch -> (char) ch)
            .forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println();
        str.chars()
            .filter(Character::isDigit)
            .forEach(IterateString::printChar);
    }
}
```

With ***streams*** you have a lot of benefits as lazy evaluation, lambda syntax, method references...
For more info follow java 8 features.

***BTW***
your code snippet has some mistakes, it should look as follows:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        ch[i] = str.charAt(i);
        System.out.println(ch[i]);
    }
```

instead of:

```
char[] xh = new char[x.length()];
for(int i=0; x.length(); i+) {
   ch[i] = x.charAt(i);
   System.out.println(ch[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is method in string `toCharArray()`

```
"aab".toCharArray()
```

But this method anyway requires additional memory for new char array

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you want to store all the characters of the string in an array? If you just want to print the characters one by one, there's no need to store them in an array.

Your `for` loop line also contains errors.

```
String x = "<BigBus><color>RED</color><number>123</number>........</BigBus>";

for(int i=0; i < x.length(); i++) {
    char c = x.charAt(i);
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
xh = x.toCharArray();
```

This'll solve the issue