# Processing: create an array of the characters within the string

Tags: processing

I am new to processing and trying to figure out a way to create an array of all the characters within a string. Currently I Have:

```java
String[] words = {"hello", "devak", "road", "duck", "face"};
String theWord = words[int(random(0,words.length))];
```

I've been googling and haven't found a good solution yet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: got it!  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10006570/5625620

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the comment you posted (which perhaps should have been an answer), there are a ton of ways to split a String.

The most obvious solution might be the `String.split()` function. If you give that function an empty String `""` as an argument, it will split every character:

```java
void setup() { 
  String myString = "testing testing 123";
  String[] chars = myString.split("");
  for (String c : chars) {
    println(c);
  }
}
```

You could also just use the `String.charAt()` function:

```java
void setup() { 
  String myString = "testing testing 123";
  for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
    char c = myString.charAt(i);
    println(c);
  }
}
```

Comment: I did that second one and it worked, but now whenever i try to check a character with an if statement, I get an error about how characters aren't strings. :/

Comment: Well, characters aren't Strings. That's true. Try posting another question with an updated [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)- you don't have to include the splitting part, just hardcode the character and what you're comparing it to.