# Java how to convert String to Iterable<Character>

Tags: java, iterator, comparable, iterable, compareto

I have a class that stores String-type data that can be compared based on the length of the string ( compareTo() ), iterated by chars ( iterator() ).

I have implemented `compareTo` method but I don't know how to implement the `iterator()`

```
public class ExtendedString implements Comparable<ExtendedString>,Iterable<Character>{
    private String str;

    public ExtendedString(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public int compareTo(ExtendedString estr) {...}

    public Iterator<Character> iterator() {
        ???
    }
}
```

My question is how should I implement `iterator()`?

Comment: Are you sure you want `Iterable<ExtendedString>` and not `Iterable<Character>`?

Answer (score 0):

1. To convert `String` to `Character[]`, we can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006165/converting-string-to-character-array-in-java#answer-27690990)
2. Use [`Arrays#stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(T%5B%5D)) method to convert the `Character[]` to `Stream<Character>`, then use [`BaseStream#iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#iterator()).

```java
@Override
public Iterator<Character> iterator() {
    return Arrays.stream(str.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).toArray(Character[]::new)).iterator();
}
```